# C# and Javascript - How to Add Remove Objects To A Javascript Array and Postback to Server?

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a form where there is a section for a user to add multiple appointment dates. This section of the form has the following fields: startdate, enddate and a add button.

```
 <form action="/someaction">
   Start Date <input type="text" id="StartDate" name="StartDate"><br>
   End Date: <input type="text" id="EndDate" name="EndDate"><br>
   <a class="btn btn-default js-add" href="#" role="button">Add</a>

    <table class="table" >
        <tbody id="dates" >

        </tbody>
    </table>

   // Other form fields

   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Each time a user adds an appointment I want to store the values in an JavaScript object array and display the number of items in the array along with details of the object added with an option to remove it from the list. Below is my initial attempt:

```
<script>
   var appointments = [];

   $(".js-add").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var startDate = $("#StartDate").val();
      var endDate = ("#EndDate").val()

      // What can I use to uniquely identify each object incase we need to delete???
      appointments.push( { startDate: startDate , endDate: endDate });

      $('<tr/>', { html: '<td >' + startDate + '</td><td>' + endDate + '</td><td><a class="js-delete" href="" data-id="">delete</a></td>'})
        .appendTo($('#dates'));
   }

    $(".js-delete").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

      // How do I remove the selected object from the array???
      // appointments.splice(x,1);

    }
</script>
```

How do I remove the object from the array using the array index. I have a data-id attribute on the delete link which would contain the array index.

But the array index can change each time an object is added or deleted so how can I update the data-id attribute on existing rows?

Secondly, how do I pass this object back to the server since it isn't attached to any form input field?

Some help would be appreciated?

Comment: You might try one question at a time. As for #2, typically you create a hidden input for things you want to post to the action.

Comment: Definitely try to restrict it to one question. 1: Where does that `data-id` attribute originally come from? How is it being set in the first place? Do you have access to that ID when you're creating an appointment? 2: [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX). Get cozy with it, you'll use it a lot.

Comment: @Crowcoder so something like `$hidInput.val(JSON.stringify(appointments));`

Comment: @Mike it comes from the following link `<a class="js-delete" href="" data-id="">delete</a>` which is created when adding a new apointment to the array. I've not populated it with any thing becuase I'm unsure what I can use as a unique identifier. I can't add the items via ajax because the appointments are part of a child relationship. They can only be added once the parent record has been created.

Comment: @adam78 I just meant you could submit the entire form through AJAX. Hidden inputs work too, totally your call. As for the ID, is it ever assigned a value? If so, how? The code you're showing creates the attribute but doesn't give it a unique value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I remove the object from the array. I have a data-id attribute on the delete link but what can I use to uniquely identify the object.

Because you create a new table row you need to:

- delegate event (i.e.: $(document).on('click', '.js-delete', function (e) {)
- use the data-id attribute to assign it the value of the index of the current 
  element in array.
- on deleting a row you need to rearrange the values of the data-id

> How do I pass this object back to the server

You may use an hidden input field and set its value with the array value.

The snippet:

```js
var appointments = [];

//
// delegated event
//
$(document).on('click', '.js-delete', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var id = +$(this).attr("data-id");
  appointments.splice(id, 1);
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  //
  // rearrange the values of data-id attributes
  //
  $('#dates tr td:nth-child(3) a').each(function(index, element) {
    var tId = +$(element).attr("data-id");
    if (tId > id) {
      $(element).attr("data-id", tId - 1);
    }
  });
});

$(function () {
  $(".js-add").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var startDate = $("#StartDate").val();
    var endDate = $("#EndDate").val();

    // In order to uniquely identify each object you can set the
    // value of data-id attribute with current array index
    appointments.push( { startDate: startDate , endDate: endDate });

    $('<tr/>', { html: '<td >' + startDate + '</td><td>' + endDate + '</td><td><a class="js-delete" href="" data-id="' + (appointments.length - 1) + '">delete</a></td>'})
    .appendTo($('#dates'));

    //
    // a possible sorting.... Consider to use a date compare
    // instead of a string compare function.
    //
    $.each($('#dates tr').get().sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.childNodes[0].textContent.localeCompare(b.childNodes[0].textContent);
    }), function(index, ele) {
      $('#dates').append(ele);
    });
  });

  //
  // On form submit stringify your array and save it into
  // an hidden input field
  //
  $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#appointments').val(JSON.stringify(appointments));
    console.log($('#appointments').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>


<form action="/someaction">
    <input id="appointments" type="hidden">
    Start Date <input type="text" id="StartDate" name="StartDate"><br>
    End Date: <input type="text" id="EndDate" name="EndDate"><br>
    <a class="btn btn-default js-add" href="#" role="button">Add</a>
    <table class="table" >
        <tbody id="dates" >

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- Other form fields -->

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'll mark this as the solution. One last question, how would I display the appointments in ascending order?

Comment: @adam78 A sorting  on table rows added. Consider the comment to your question: put on hold as too broad.

Comment: Why does C# require an index inside the brackets? Makes everything more painful. It should be able to figure out the array index without it being explicit by just following in order and incrementing as it sees additional instances of a name. PHP does this just fine...

Comment: @jjxtra I may agree with you, but there is no c# in answer and question. By mistake the c# tag is only part of answer tag. In any case there is a difference between javascript and php. For more details you can take a look to [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)